# IMAP question regarding last email with getSubject().contains

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, imap

I'm doing some automation and I found that when I retrieve emails that I'm getting the same subject header (This is expected). So when i do the code below i would get the body of the old emails since they are not being deleted.

```
Message.getSubject().contains(*the name of the header)
```

How do i get the latest email when i search for the header subject?

My first thought is to sort it somehow but does IMAP have a capability built it?

I tried doing some sort of array sort but doesn't seem to work and i read that IMAP only does dates?

Comment: Does your server support the `SORT` extension?  If not, and you're not moving between folders a lot, just choose the one with the highest UID.

Comment: Do you want the last message *received*, or the message *sent most recently*?  The last message received is the last message in the Inbox.  To get the last message sent, you'll need to sort by sent date, which can either be done using [IMAPFolder.getSortedMessages](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/com/sun/mail/imap/IMAPFolder.html#getSortedMessages-com.sun.mail.imap.SortTerm:A-) method, if your server supports the SORT extension, or by sorting the Message array locally.